# Has a disk drive repair removed Ubuntu from my computer?

Tags: boot-repair

(Apologies for wrong/poor terminology and tags, I'm not too great with tech jargon)

My computer had been working fine up till this afternoon. I picked it up to use it but the screen wouldn't show anything when I opened the lid, which sometimes happens. No biggie, I just turn off using the power key, and restart the computer.

Usually a boot menu comes up to select if I want to use Ubuntu or Windows 10, but it didn't appear this time. Instead, it went to a screen saying that Windows 10 didn't load properly and prompted me to restart the laptop. I did, and it it came up with a count down to repairing the C disk drive. I wasn't sure what to do so let the laptop do its thing.

During this, I noticed that one of the compartments under my laptop had popped out somehow, with one of the pegs that keep it in place poking above the laptop shell, and I could see a green motherboard underneath. I tried to push the peg back in but to no avail, so I waited for the disk drive to finish repairing, then switched the computer off to unscrew the compartment and put everything in properly (I didn't touch the board). Upon booting, it now just takes me straight to the Windows 10 login screen, and when I bring up the boot menu, Ubuntu is no longer listed as an option.

I no longer have the USB I installed Ubuntu on, and rarely use Windows 10 as it is hideously and unbelievably slow, so all of my files are on Ubuntu. Is there anyway to get Ubuntu back or do I have to get a new USB drive and essentially start everything again?

Comment: If the Ubuntu partitions are still intact, you can use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to make it bootable. You can also just copy the files, but either way, an Ubuntu USB driver should be needed.

Comment: If no usb drive is handy, and you have a DVD drive and empty DVD you can use that instead.  Will make your Win 10 seem fast, but will get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to get Ubuntu back or do I have to get a new USB drive and essentially start everything again?

Boot from a live USB and check the partitions it shows in Nautilus. If you can see the Ubuntu partitions run [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Windows has likely overwritten your boot sector and removed Grub. Grub is needed to boot multiple operating systems that are not Microsoft related. If that works you recreated dual boot.

It the partitions are not shown you likely did a restore from the internal Windows recovery partition. That will remove Ubuntu and set it back to "factory settings". In that was activated though you would have gotten a warning that the system is going to do that. The 1st scenario is more likely.

Always make backups and keep those backups outside of that machine.

Comment: I've tried to fix things to the best of my ability but to no avail, and have reinstalled Ubuntu. However, it still isn't showing on the boot screen and I'm very stuck on how to continue.

Answer (score 1):

Windows has a boot menu and likes to take over the boot process that Ubuntu has already put in place and put itself first.  Even if you modify it to put Ubuntu first.  You can override this by going into the UEFI or BIOS options on boot.  I ran into this a bunch with my home computer which always switched to a Windows only boot when I had Windows and Ubuntu installed.  Pressing and holding down `shift`, I believe, when clicking shutdown, yes in Windows, will allow for selecting a few more options one of which is UEFI options, although it may be called something else.  This should allow for modifying the options to get into Ubuntu.  There's also applications which can modify the boot of the system.